# Angular - error NG8001: 'app-landing-topnavbar' is not a known element

Tags: angular

I am using Angular-11 for a particular project:

I have this modules: app.module.ts, layout.module.ts, landing.module.ts

landing.component.html is the default

In layout.module, I have:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeadernavbarComponent } from './headernavbar/headernavbar.component';
import { FooternavbarComponent } from './footernavbar/footernavbar.component';
import { AsidenavbarComponent } from './asidenavbar/asidenavbar.component';
import { SettingnavbarComponent } from './settingnavbar/settingnavbar.component';
import { LandingTopnavbarComponent } from './landing-topnavbar/landing-topnavbar.component';
import { LandingFooternavbarComponent } from './landing-footernavbar/landing-footernavbar.component';  

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeadernavbarComponent,
    FooternavbarComponent,
    AsidenavbarComponent,
    SettingnavbarComponent,
    LandingTopnavbarComponent,
    LandingFooternavbarComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    HeadernavbarComponent,
    FooternavbarComponent,
    AsidenavbarComponent,
    SettingnavbarComponent,
    LandingTopnavbarComponent,
    LandingFooternavbarComponent
  ],
imports: [
  CommonModule
 ]
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

Also, in landing.module.ts I have:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LandingRoutingModule } from './landing-routing.module';
import { LandingComponent } from './landing.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '../../layout/layout.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LandingComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    LandingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LandingRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule
  ]
})
export class LandingModule { }
```

LandingComponent is the default, and I have it this way in the app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { LandingComponent } from './features/landing/landing.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/landing', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'landing', component: LandingComponent },
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

landing.component.html appears this way:

```
<body class="hold-transition layout-top-nav">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <app-landing-topnavbar></app-landing-topnavbar>

    <app-landing-footernavbar></app-landing-footernavbar>
  </div>

</body>
```

When I served the application, I got this error:

```
Error: src/app/features/landing/landing.component.html:3:5 - error NG8001: 'app-landing-topnavbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-landing-topnavbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-landing-topnavbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3     <app-landing-topnavbar></app-landing-topnavbar>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/features/landing/landing.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Error occurs in the template of component LandingComponent.

  Error: src/app/features/landing/landing.component.html:5:5 - error NG8001: 'app-landing-footernavbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-landing-footernavbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-landing-footernavbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

5     <app-landing-footernavbar></app-landing-footernavbar>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/features/landing/landing.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component LandingComponent.
```

When I removed:

```
    <app-landing-topnavbar></app-landing-topnavbar>

    <app-landing-footernavbar></app-landing-footernavbar>
```

from landing.component.html

I got another error:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'landing'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'landing'
```

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `selector` for `LandingTopnavbarComponent`?

Comment: @rveerd - @Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-topnavbar',
  templateUrl: './landing-topnavbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-topnavbar.component.scss']
})

Comment: Perhaps some sources are not included in the build? Check the build log or use webpack-bundle-analyzer. Has the project been updated from an older version of Angular?

Comment: @rveerd - No, it's a new project